# How to delete duplicate rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following data:

```
Id: 1       Name:   apple       ForeignKey: 10
Id: 2       Name:   apple       ForeignKey: 10
Id: 3       Name:   apple       ForeignKey: 15
Id: 4       Name:   peach       ForeignKey: 11
Id: 5       Name:   peach       ForeignKey: 12
```

Rows with same Name and ForeignKey are duplicates in my case. Now I want to remove all the duplicates except one instance from the table.

In other words; I want to remove all rows but one, where Name and ForeignKey are equal.

In case with upper data only the row with Id 2 OR Id 1 should be removed.

With

```
select count(Name), Name, ForeignKey group by Name, ForeignKey having count(Name)>1
```

I am able to find items where more than 1 row with same Name and Foreign key exist, but how to get the IDs of those rows? And how to get the IDs of those rows except the first/last occurrence of that row with same Name and ForeignKey?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Once you mopped the floor, remember to *fix the leak* - if you don't want duplicates in your database, apply a unique constraint against `(Name,ForeignKey)` (once you've removed the duplicates once)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever fixing the leak was the first I have done ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete duplicate data from SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514081/how-do-i-delete-duplicate-data-from-sql-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer if database specific, but here is how you can do it joining the table to itself:

```
delete t1
from yourtable t1
    join yourtable t2 on t1.id > t2.id
        and t1.name = t2.name 
        and t1.foreignkey = t2.foreignkey
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c122/1)

Comment: WOW, that was fast. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a CTE & window function, deleting the duplicate rows by counting the number of rows that are the same, and then deleting all but one.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc217/2)

```
;WITH myvals
AS (
    SELECT [id]
        ,[name]
        ,[foreignkey]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [name]
            ,[foreignkey] ORDER BY [id]
                ,[name]
                ,[foreignkey]
            ) AS inst_count
    FROM yourtable
    )
DELETE
FROM myvals
WHERE inst_count > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

delete x from 
(
  select *, rn=row_number() over (partition by name,foreignkey order by name)
  from yourtable
) x
where rn > 1